# Parsing HEX result in different values

Tags: java, hex

I am trying to migrate (from javascript to java) a function to decode hex values.
The problem is when I try to convert "5CDF" to Int.

JAVASCRIPT

```
ParseInt("5CDF") // Return 5
```

JAVA

```
Integer.parseInt("5CDF") // Exception
Integer.parseInt("5CDF",16) // Return 23775
```

How should I do to convert "5CDF" to 5 in Java?

Comment: @Kanaiya I don't think it is a good idea to change posted code... why do you *know* it is `"5CDF7"` and not `"5CDF"` as originally posted, and repeated two more times?

Comment: If you want to ignore hex digits above 9, then you aren’t decoding hex values, are you?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, `5CDF` == 23775 in the decimal system.

So the question is, do you want the hex value decoded or the 5 in front?

Comment: Hi @alexxarisis, Here are other examples in Javascript. As you say, I need the first number I think. Example : 65CF = 65 or 7D72 = 7. So I believe that Javascript parse until a letter comes.

Comment: @sebacipo If the first numbers are what you are looking for you can simply do `String nums = s.split("(?=\\D)")[0];` and then parse it to int.
There are a lot other ways to do this as well.
But I would be mindful of the javascript function, because maybe it was just wrong from the start and you actually need the real answer.